# Why is this Spring test trying to autowire beans it should not be able to see?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Here's my `SubjectTest`:

```
package com.sandbox.autowireintest;

import com.sandbox.autowireintest.configuration.TestConfig;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class SubjectTest {

    @Autowired
    Subject subject;

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Here's the `TestConfig`:

```
package com.sandbox.autowireintest.configuration;

import com.sandbox.autowireintest.AutowireInTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public AutowireInTest autowireInTest() {
        return mock(AutowireInTest.class);
    }

}
```

This test fails on startup with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autowireInTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest com.sandbox.autowireintest.AutowireInTest.ignoreInTest; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest com.sandbox.autowireintest.AutowireInTest.ignoreInTest; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 46 more
```

Here's the other classes:

```
package com.sandbox.autowireintest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Subject {

    @Autowired
    AutowireInTest autowireInTest;

}
```

And:

```
package com.sandbox.autowireintest;

import com.sandbox.ignoreintest.IgnoreInTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AutowireInTest {

    @Autowired
    IgnoreInTest ignoreInTest;

}
```

And:

```
package com.sandbox.ignoreintest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class IgnoreInTest {
}
```

Here's my pom for version info:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sandbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

1. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  `Subject` autowires `AutowireInTest`.  `AutowireInTest` autowires `IgnoreInTest`, but I'm assuming the `TestConfig` should overwrite `AutowireInTest` and replace it with a mock that does not have the autowire to `IgnoreInTest`.  So why does this test still start with this error?

   My goal is to avoid using a real `AutowireInTest` in my test and context, but I do have other autowired classes in my `Subject` (not in this code, but in my real code I'm trying to test) that I do want to autowire.  How do I achieve this?
2. If anything, I would expect this test to fail saying it can't find `Subject`.  My `TestConfig` only has a `@Bean` for `AutowireInTest`, so how does my test know how to autowire `Subject`? I haven't told it to scan anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mock object is an instance of a dynamically created class that extends the class being mocked. The class being mocked has fields annotated with `@Autowired`. So Spring is supposed to autowire these fields. But it can't because the beans to autowire don't exist, hence the exception.

There is no reason to load a Spring context to implement a unit test. Just use Mockito without Spring:

```
@InjectMocks
private Subject subject;

@Mock
private AutowireInTest mockAutowizeInTest;

@Before
public void prepare() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Iy fou used constructor injection, the problem you're facing would become obvious, because the dependencies wouldbe explicit, and you wouldn't need the annotation support of Mockito:

```
AutowireInTest mockAutowireInTest = mock(AutowireInTest.class);
Subject subject = new Subject(mockAutowireInTest);
```

Regarding your second question: the est would fail later if it went until there. But it can't go until there because it can't even create the beans referenced in the context.

Comment: In *this* code there is no reason, but "My goal is to avoid using a real AutowireInTest in my test and context, but I do have other autowired classes in my Subject (not in this code, but in my real code I'm trying to test) that I do want to autowire. How do I achieve this?"

Comment: Also, I don't understand how it explains the problem.  Outside of this context, AFAIK, if I `@Autowire` a bean and define it in a config with a `@Bean`, it would work without issue.

Comment: "But it can't because the beans to autowire don't exist, hence the exception.", don't they exist in my TestConfig?

Comment: What don't you understand? The mock object you define is an instance of a class. This class extends AutowireInTest. AutowireInTest has a  field of type IgnoreInTest that is annotated as Autowired. This tells Spring that this field must be autowired with a bean of type IgnoreInTest. So Spring tries doing it. So it looks for a bean of type IgnoreInTest, but can't find any. So it fails. You haven't defined any bean of type IgnoreInTest in your test config, have you?

Comment: For the question "how to achieve this?": inject interfaces instead of concrete classes and/or use constructor injection.

Comment: Ah I get what you're saying now.  I didn't realize that the `mock` has an autowired field in it.